# Why would I create a public class that has all static properties?

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns

I am noticing in a current code base I am working with that a previous developer has a couple public classes that do not inherit from any other classes but are filled with static properties. Is this another way of creating a struct or enum? Is this an older or newer technique of housing static data that can be referenced? I find it odd/different to see a class built in this way but am wondering what the Stack Overflow community feels about what this coder was trying to accomplish.

***EDITED to add an example***

```
    public class Deal
    {
        public Deal() { }

        public static decimal Fee
        {
            get { return (decimal)25; }
        }

        public static decimal MaximumAmount
        {
            get ( return (decimal)300; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume that the previous developers just understand a class as a hodgepodge for global variables. Now you know why they are  _former_ developers.

Comment: I'm guessing @TimSchmelter is spot on. I inherited the same kind of thing a while back. It's just a dumping ground for global variables. Yuck!

Comment: Can `new Deal()` be called more than once? That is a bad sign.

Answer (score 1):

A public class with only static properties is essentially a container for global variables.

This could be poor design, but there are also valid reasons for such a design.

For example, the [System.Web.HttpRuntime class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.aspx) is a container for global information about a web application and the [System.Windows.Forms.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx) class is a container for global information about a WinForms application.  The [System.Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class is a container for information about the current environment and platform.